# My SQL query to display most helpful reviews from users review

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I want to run a Ecommerce website and going to sale products. I want to get rating & review from each users to improve the quality. So on a separate page, i want to get the rating & review from users. So other users can mark the review is useful or not useful. So when ever the users select the posted review is useful or not, i will make a DB entry in the new table. 
So my requirement is, on a new page i want to list the reviews based on most helpful reviews from users selection.

So i want to show the results based on most count of helpful reviews first(in Descending order)

My table structure as follows.
rating_review table:
[image]
rating_review_helpful table

[image]

I have pasted my sql query below.

```
SELECT *,
       rating_reviews_helpful.rating_id,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM `rating_reviews_helpful`
JOIN rating_reviews ON rating_reviews.shop_id = rating_reviews_helpful.deal_id
JOIN users ON users.user_id=rating_reviews.user_id
WHERE rating_reviews_helpful.review_helpful =1
  AND rating_reviews.rating_status = 1
  AND rating_reviews_helpful.deal_id = 12
  AND rating_reviews_helpful.type = 2
GROUP BY rating_reviews_helpful.rating_id
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

Result for the above query is as follows.
[image]

I have stuck on this for a long time. Can any one help me to get out of this? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why did you join on `rating_reviews.shop_id = rating_reviews_helpful.deal_id`? Shouldn't that be something like `rating_reviews.rating_id = rating_reviews_helpful.rating_id`?

Comment: rating_reviews.shop_id is product id in rating review table. So here am mapping the product id in the rating helpful table (deal_id)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try the following query to get the result

  SELECT (add all the fields you require) ,B.rating_id
FROM    `rating_reviews_helpful` rrh1
JOIN rating_reviews rr1 ON rr1.shop_id = rrh1.deal_id
JOIN users u1 ON u1.user_id=rr1.user_id JOIN (SELECT rrh.rating_id rating_id,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM `rating_reviews_helpful` rrh
JOIN rating_reviews rr ON rr.shop_id = rrh.deal_id
JOIN users u ON u.user_id=rr.user_id
WHERE rrh.review_helpful =1
  AND rr.rating_status = 1
  AND rrh.deal_id = 12
  AND rrh.type = 2
GROUP BY rrh.rating_id) B ON rrh1.rating_id = B.rating_id
WHERE rrh1.review_helpful =1
  AND rrh1 = 1
  AND rrh1.deal_id = 12
  AND rrh1.type = 2
ORDER BY B.COUNT DESC
```

Comment: When i run the above query, got the following error.. #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias ..